# Custom Spring Boot Starter doesn't load profile's config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I have a custom spring boot starter and an app (let's call it just an app). The starter is a dependency on the app. The starter has two configuration YML files for two profiles: dev and prom.

Before I run my app, I specify which profile I want to run in VM options in Idea, and if I choose the dev profile I expect it to read **application-dev.yml** from the app and read the **application-dev.yml** from the starter. It reads the app's **application-dev.yml** just fine, but it doesn't see the starter's config at all.

If you have any suggestions, or if you encountered this problem previously I would be glad to read your replies, thank you in advance!

I specified `spring.profiles.active` in the **application.yml** in the starter, but it didn't change anything and the app still doesn't see the **application-dev.yml** from the starter.

I tried jar tf on the starter's jar file and the **application-dev.yml** is here. When I tried jar tf on the app's jar file I didn't see the starter's **application-dev.yml**

Comment: add in vm argument as spring.profiles.active=dev  then it will work

Comment: @spandey i already did this (sorry i didn't mention it in the post), but i guess it loads the config of the app, not the starter